# How to keep preferences saved even on un-installing app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want my app to remember the preferences.we wont keep our app on play store.every time after reinstalling(next version) the app preferences are getting deleted.how can i resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data save for an android app after it uninstall or force data clear from settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719922/data-save-for-an-android-app-after-it-uninstall-or-force-data-clear-from-setting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029377/sharedpreferences-not-being-removed-on-user-uninstalling-application

Answer (score 0):

From [Data save for an android app after it uninstall or force data clear from settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719922/data-save-for-an-android-app-after-it-uninstall-or-force-data-clear-from-setting), you can use a Google Backup. You can also try to create an external file that saves data.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html (choose external for saving)

However, the user can delete the files.